# how can you combine a form variable and a submit action with one click

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on a website that has a dropdown box and instead of a normal submit button I need to have a button marked yes and one marked no.

So I want to store the value of the dropdown box and keep a note of whether the user pressed yes or no.

Normally I would have a drop down then a radio button for yes/no and then submit but I want to combine the action of clicking yes or no into both storing/passing the value and submitting the form.

How could I do that? I don't mind some Javascript if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only clicked submit buttons will be successful:

```
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="Yes">
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="No">
```

Comment: I have at present: <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">